# django viewflow how to mock viewflow handlers

Tags: python, django-viewflow

Say I have a flow class `app1/flows.py`

```py
class MyFlow(Flow):
    start = ...
    do_stuff = flow.Handler(this.do_stuff_handler).Next(...)
    end = ...

    def do_stuff_handler(self, activation):
        ...
```

If I want to mock `do_stuff_handler` to assert if it has been called

```py
class MyFlowTest(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('app1.flows.MyFlow.do_stuff_handler')
    def test_do_stuff_handler_called(self, mock_do_stuff_handler):
        ...
```

It appears the `do_stuff_handler` did not get patched. I did notice the flow class gets instantiated when starting up Django see [here](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/issues/290) I am struggling to find the correct path to patch the handler method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this-references are resolved at a class import time, and kept inside flow.Handler member variable.

So I think mocking the `app1.flows.MyFlow.instance.do_stuff.handler` could helps